# How to transfer a string read from libxml2 via libcurl?

Tags: c, linux, http, libcurl, libxml2

I need to send a http-post request to server. I choose to use libcurl functions. The request data must be like xml-format. Therefor, I use libxml2 to convert the string to a xml, then I read the xml file into a buf, pass the buf to libcurl, finish the post request.
  The xml file which is created by libxml2 in in encoding-utf8, when I send the data to the libcurl function, it seems like to be normal. But I catch the package to the server, found that the english characters are all normal, but the mother language of mine "Chinese" is replaced by a '?', well, it really confused me a lot.
  What should I do now, can I set the libcurl function to transfer utf-8 string ?
  Well, my testing envirmonent is linux c .
  This is my xml created by libxml2 :

```
<vehicleName>±GM7180LE AT</vehicleName>
```

You can see, english characters are all normal. The first two characters are all chinese.
They should be "别克". The libxml2 automatically convert it from gb2312 to utf8.

```
xmlSaveFormatFileEnc(createXML, doc, "UTF-8", 1);
```

Then I send the string read from this xml to the libcurl functions, but I found the truth is: the server received data is not like ±GM but ??GM.
    The libcurl code is
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, ip_addr);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, requestMsg);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, strlen(requestMsg));
    What should I do now?

Answer Alfe:
the libxml2 code is like:

```
char licenseNo_text[20] = "沪33333";
licenseNo = xmlNewNode(NULL, BAD_CAST "licenseNo");
content = xmlNewText(BAD_CAST licenseNo_text);
xmlAddChild(QueryVehicleModelRequest, licenseNo);
xmlAddChild(licenseNo, content);
```

After I add nodes to the xml file, I read it into a buf:

```
while ((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (ch != '\n')
            buf[i++] = ch;
    }
```

I think the buf is already in utf-8, so I directly pass it to the libcurl  function:

```
ret = func_libcurl(buf, headerfilename, bodyfilename);
```

func_libcurl code is, requestMsg is http-post head and body:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, ip_addr);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, requestMsg);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, strlen(requestMsg));
```

headerfilename, bodyfilename are file descriptors, to save data from server response.

At last, I use libxml2 to parse the file "bodyfilename". The file "bodyfilename" saved response data from the server. It is in utf-8, and I can successfully parse it into gb2312.

That's all.

Comment: It's an encoding problem, obviously.  Please describe in more detail (some source code would be nice) what exactly you are doing.  Often the trouble results from something small like a missing prefix `u` before a string literal or similar.

Comment: in the question, I describe it:@Alfe

Comment: Could be that your compiler already converts the non-latin characters.  Please add some debug output after defining `licenseNo_text` like `printf("%02x", licenseNo_text[i])` for `i` in 0..3.  This should show us in which encoding the Chinese character exists.  `sizeof(licenseNo_text[0])` should be 1 by standard definition, but one never knows, so maybe you could give this out as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_The documentation for the [`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTPOSTFIELDS) flag says "You must make sure that the data is formatted the way you want the server to receive it. libcurl will not convert or encode it for you. *Most web servers will assume this data to be url-encoded*." Try using [`curl_easy_escape()`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_escape.html) on your data, and using that as the post data for your request.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Just now, I tried this function in my program. But when I compile it. It gived me an error:: undefined reference to `curl_easy_escape'. It doesn't work.But before , curl_easy_setopt works well.

Comment: This is my makefile:
target:
    gcc -I /usr/local/include -o http-post http-post.c -lcurl

Comment: Undefined reference to curl_easy_escape? Are you using the current version of libcurl?

Comment: Ah, I see. The availability is "Added in 7.15.4 and replaces the old [`curl_escape(3)`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_escape.html) function."

Comment: Yes, I downloaded libcurl library from the website. It's the new version. But in my linux os, it has an old one. It dosn't have curl_easy_escape function. How could I make the new one available?
In the makefile, -lcurl seems to work not well .

Comment: Well, if you're using an old version of curl, try using `curl_escape()`. Otherwise, the `-L` command-line argument tells gcc where to look for libraries.

Comment: Yes, I use "-L/usr/local/lib", tell gcc to find libraries. But a new error occupy:error while loading shared libraries: libcurl.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
But I have libcurl.so.4 in /usr/local/lib .

Comment: And who owns it? And is it a symbolic link to something that doesn't exist? (Note: this conversation appears to have reached its limit of usefulness. Troubleshooting your compilation environment is beyond my capacity, not to mention local scope.)

Comment: I decide to use the old function curl_escape() now. The server want to receive UTF-8 request. If I convert my request string from gb2312 to UTF-8 first, then pass the converted string to crul_escape(),  will the server receive the right request?

Comment: I don't know. I've never used libcurl. My recommendation was based on an analysis of the stated problem, and reading the documentation, which I pointed you at.

Comment: I succeed. Thanks a lot, this really helps me a lot. Thank you.